# Drawing a view through animation is very slow because of list view inside it

Tags: android, animation, draw

I am animating a view which has list view inside it through drawing. i.e setting the height from 0 to particular height.when list-view is empty my view draws smoothly.but when list-view is populated my view animates very slowly.

here is my animation code

```
public static void expand(final View v) {   

v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     

MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
      final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

      v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
      v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Animation a = new Animation()
      {
       @Override
       protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
          ? 500
            : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        v.requestLayout();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
       }
      };

      // 1dp/ms
      a.setDuration(500);
      v.startAnimation(a);
     }
```

here is my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/recent_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#FF0000"
   android:layout_marginTop="130px"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"


    >

<ListView

            android:id="@+id/callslist_history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/top"

            />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

initial height of my view is 0dp then on expand i animate its height to 500dp.but this animation works smoothly only when list-view is not populated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old question but for possible future reference:

I had this same issue and just solved it by wrapping the view (which is being animated) inside framelayout and setting the child's height/width to the target values of the animation and instead of resizing the view in animation I changed the position (x/y) of the view.